maven build doesnt pull transitive dependency for jackson core
I have written a java sdk with following dependency:
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.0</version>
</dependency>

SDK works as expected on its own.
Dependency tree:
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.18.0:compile

Then I include this SDK as a dependency to a client program. But program fails with error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeature

Class JacksonFeature is part of jackson-core. And dependency tee:
[INFO] com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.18.0:compile

Why doesn't maven build pull jackson-core dependency?

Probably, the client program was not built as fat JAR, i.e. including dependencies. Use Maven assembly plugin or Maven shade plugin for that.
